# Python exifread - Parsing difficulties

Tags: python, import, module, exif

I'm trying to get the coordinates of a number of photos, i.e. I'm trying to get the exif data using a python script. The goal is to georeference all the photos and display their locations on a map. I am encountering problems with exif, however. I'm on Windows (64bit) and installed the corresponding (Strawberry) Perl software and then the Exiftool module (version 12.30) using Anaconda (Navigator), but to no avail. It gives me the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exif'`. If I use the command `pip install exif` it tells me that the requirements are already met. What am I missing here? I'll gladly provide more information if required.

... I also tried an alternative: the module exifread works without import problems but does not seem to have all the necessary functionality (I can read the coordinates, but can't handle the extraction of the coordinates, it gives me a IfdTag-object when I would like an array of the degrees, minutes and seconds that I can then further process.)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `conda` to install the package, not `pip`?  It could be installing the library to the wrong instance of Python.

Comment: `ExifTool` is Perl software, I don't see how you try to install it in python. You may use it via `subprocess`. There are however modules - e.g. `exifread` works as well reading exif data with `Pillow` - I used both. Maybe share your code that produce `IfdTag-object`

Comment: @MarkTolonen, thank you for your answer. While what you say makes sense to me, it seems that on anaconda there is no "exif" package - check out  [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/search?q=exif). Therefore, `conda` install fails. Do you happen to have another idea on how to go on about this?

Comment: @buran, thanks for your input. The subprocess construct sounds interesting. Right now I lack the time to have a deeper look at it, however, so I'll try to make it work with exifread. The code that produces the `IfdTag-object` goes like this:
`for file_name in file_names:
    file_path=f'{relevant_path}\\{file_name}'
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    y_degree = tags['GPS GPSLatitude']
    x_degree = tags['GPS GPSLongitude']`
I would then like to use `x_degree` and `y_degree` but fail to access them in a reasonable manner.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include your code as properly formatted code block.

Comment: Also, edit the title and the question to do a better job at explaining that you have difficulty to parse exif info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility function [`exifread.utils.get_gps_coord()`](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/blob/91eaba1725e91aef301f9b5699d51515df9a1326/exifread/utils.py#L56) that provides convenient method to access coordinates as tuple in the format `(latitude, longitude)`. Note negative value for `latitude` means `South`, negative value for `longitude` - `West`

example

```
import exifread
path = 'image.jpg'
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    tags = exifread.process_file(f, details=False)

coord = exifread.utils.get_gps_coords(tags)
print(coord)
```

For sake of completeness, there are also other modules to work with exif:

- [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) - there is functionality to work with exif
- [piexif](https://pypi.org/project/piexif/)

Also, as mentioned in the comments - you can use [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) (Perl software), via `subprocess`